# Trouble persisting in an EJB project

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb, wildfly

I'm really needing some help here: I'm making my very first EJB project (3.2) with JPA 2.2 and in a WildFly application server with MySQL database. I'm trying to persist data using my EJB bean but getting a really huge and "says-nothing-to-me" error when the method is executed (called from a managed bean). I really have NO IDEA of what may be causing it (I thought it might have something to do with JTA but I'm not sure - really newbie in all these stuff).

I'm also not sure if this design is a good idea: I'm not using a DAO object in this example and I'm not sure about how should I be using it.

Do you guys have any idea of where should I start looking for the problem?

This is my Managed Bean. Nothing special here:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TesteMB {

    @Inject private TesteORM testeORM;

    @EJB private BaseEJBLocal baseService;

    public void gravar() {
        this.baseService.adiciona(this.testeORM);
    }

    public TesteORM getTesteORM() {
        return testeORM;
    }

    public void setTesteORM(TesteORM testeORM) {
        this.testeORM = testeORM;
    }

}
```

This is my EJB bean class (I removed the implementation of the interface because I read somewhere that it's not necessary in EJB 3.2... is that right?)

```
@Stateless
public class BaseEJBBean {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    public void add(TestORM orm) {
        this.em.persist(orm);
    }
}
```

Here is my DAO class. I noticed that when I debug the code, it doesn't seem that it's passing through the EJB class (I put a breakpoint there and it goes straight to another breakpoint in the DAO class even not calling it anywhere... why is that?). I'm getting a null pointer in the second line of the constructor:

```
public class BaseDAO<T extends Entidade> {

    private final EntityManagerFactory factory;
    private final EntityManager em;
    private Class<T> clazz;

    public BaseDAO() {
        this.factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("caixaeestoque");
        this.em = factory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void insert(T orm) {
        em.persist(orm);
    }

}
```

Here is the root cause of my exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.getStatus(JtaStatusHelper.java:76)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.isActive(JtaStatusHelper.java:118)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransaction.join(CMTTransaction.java:149)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.joinTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.postInit(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:210)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.(EntityManagerImpl.java:91)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.internalCreateEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:345)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:313)
>     at br.com.meisa.caixaeestoque.comum.BaseDAO.(BaseDAO.java:15)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:113)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.invokeAroundConstructCallbacks(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:87)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:74)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractInstantiator.newInstance(AbstractInstantiator.java:28)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.produce(BasicInjectionTarget.java:116)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.produce(BeanInjectionTarget.java:194)
>     at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:149)     at
>   org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:69)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:742)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectableReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:840)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:92)
>     at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:370)  at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:381)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector$1.proceed(DefaultInjector.java:71)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:73)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.StatelessSessionBeanInjector.inject(StatelessSessionBeanInjector.java:58)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ejb.SessionBeanInjectionTarget.inject(SessionBeanInjectionTarget.java:140)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionContext.inject(WeldInjectionContext.java:39)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInjectionInterceptor.java:51)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptorFactory.java:109)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptorFactory.java:109)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.AroundConstructInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(AroundConstructInterceptorFactory.java:28)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.java:56)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsCreateInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsCreateInterceptor.java:94)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:273)
>     ... 101 more

Comment: Do you have a persistence.xml?  Take a look at some simple examples, [here is one](http://www.thejavageek.com/2015/01/09/creating-jsf-ejb-jpa-application-using-eclipse-wildfly/) that can get you started.

Comment: If you are using EJB 3.2 you don't have to define local interfaces or any interfaces at all.. just get rid of it. Or please post the contents of the interface, the error message mentions "addiciona" method

Comment: What is the root cause of the exception? That part represents the answer.

Comment: Hi BalusC! I know it will sound a very stupid question, but how do I identify the root cause in the error message? It's a very long message and I'm not even able to post the whole thing here, but what I posted is the beggining of the error message.

Comment: The root cause is the last exception of the stack trace. All exceptions there above are just subsequent consequences of the lower exceptions. This is not different in Java EE from basic Java.

Comment: Hi BalusC! Thanks for the tip... I posted the root cause here and knowing what it means gave me the idea of debugging it a little bit. I'm getting a null pointer in my entity manager and it seems that it ignores my EJB bean. I'm not really sure of what is going on here... I don't know much about EJB...

Comment: I changed the post, actually, so you can see the whole code...

Comment: I just found out that when I'm using JTA I'm not supposed to create my Entity Manager. I tried to remove it from my DAO constructor, put a @PersistenceContext attribute there and remove the other from my BaseEJBBean class. It seems to be the solution, but I'm having another issue so I'm not sure (can't deploy the project anymore). Should it be the solution?

Comment: Next time you get an exception, just copypaste the message and 1st line of the root cause into a search engine: [example](http://google.com/search?q=java.lang.NullPointerException+at+org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.getStatus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a little long to realize that since I was using JTA I'm not allowed to instantiate a new Entity Manager (yeah, I know: newbie here).

So I removed the whole constructor in BaseDAO class and simply annotated it with @PersistenceContext:

```
private final static String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "caixaeestoque";

@PersistenceContext(unitName= PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME)
private EntityManager em;
```

Hope it helps someone else who's starting in EJB and full applications just like I was when I posted this question!